# Sticky tag for file is not a branch - CVS

Tags: java, eclipse, version-control, cvs, eclipse-kepler

I'm trying to commit my changes to the repository server (using CVS) in Eclipse Kepler, but when I do I get the following error which I've never seen before:

> The server reported an error while performing the "cvs commit"
>   command. ProsperityMobile: cvsntsrv server: sticky tag `1.6' for file`
>   src/com/prosperity/mobile/controller/UserController.java' is not a
>   branch ProsperityMobile: cvsntsrv server: sticky tag `1.14' for file`
>   src/com/prosperity/mobile/service/UserService.java' is not a branch
>   ProsperityMobile: cvsntsrv [server aborted]: correct above errors
>   first!

And honestly I don't even know where to start trouble shooting this or what it even means. Any point in the right direction would really be appreciated!

Comment: Your sources in Eclipse workspace may not be the latest version (HEAD).  Save your changes in other places first, and then update the copy in Eclipse to latest version.  Merge your changes and then commit again.

Answer (score 12):

I just came upon this too. This may happen, when you checkout a specific version of a file or at some specific date, see [Sticky tags](http://cvsnt.org/manual2/html/Sticky-tags.html) for more.

In my case, the files had a sticky tag, but were also at the HEAD. So I could just remove the sticky tag with

```
cvs update -A file.h file.cpp
```

and then proceed with `cvs commit`

---

And again when you're on a branch, it works more or less the same. Just update to the relevant branch with option `-r`

```
cvs update -r <branch-name> file.h file.cpp
```

Answer (score 6):

In order to remove sticky tag from a file in CVS, easily use:

```
cvs update -A  filename
```

Answer (score 3):

A Tag applies to a specific revision of a file or tree of files. Trying to Commit changes to that wouldn't make sense, and in fact isn't supported by the server. This is why you check things out from a Branch, make changes and then check them back into the branch. A branch is expected to change over time while tags are expected to always point you back to the specific revision.

http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Essential_CVS/Using_CVS/Tagging_and_Branching

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem in Eclipse, and updating would not work.
What worked was:

- Right click on file
- Replace with > Another Branch or Version
- Confirm (this will override local changes, therefore you should backup them)
- Select  HEAD (or the branch you need)

Comment: Thank you, simply "Override and update" did not work, your method yes.